# Obtaining Child element via LookUp/Something better

Tags: c#, parent-child

I am trying to obtain a child element of a parent element. I have a basic database as so:

```
public class list
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Users> UsersList{ get; set; }

    public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int Users_id{ get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I was wanting to obtain all of the of the elements in Users that had the specific UserId how would I do that? I am trying to refrain from using a nested for loop and iterating through all my entries of List and Users in the database. I was looking up the LookUp(), but am a bit confused on how to apply it in this case. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're a bit confused, I'll provide more detail than my original answer.  Let's take your code and create a very basic and crude sample program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace SOSample
{
    public class list
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<Users> UsersList { get; set; }

        public class Users
        {
            [Key]
            public int Users_id { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Instantiate and initialize with sample data.
            var sampleList = new list()
            {
                id = 12345,
                UsersList = new List<list.Users>()
                {
                    new list.Users() { Users_id = 1, UserId = "0042" },
                    new list.Users() { Users_id = 2, UserId = "0019" },
                    new list.Users() { Users_id = 3, UserId = "0036" },
                    new list.Users() { Users_id = 4, UserId = "0214" },
                    new list.Users() { Users_id = 5, UserId = "0042" },
                    new list.Users() { Users_id = 6, UserId = "0042" },
                    new list.Users() { Users_id = 7, UserId = "0019" }
                }
            };

            // Linq search.
            var someId = "0042";
            var linqQuery = sampleList.UsersList.Where(user => user.UserId == someId);

            Console.WriteLine("Linq query results:");
            foreach (var r in linqQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Users_id: {r.Users_id}, UserId: {r.UserId}");
            }

            // Lookup search (using same someId as for Linq).
            var lookup = sampleList.UsersList.ToLookup(user => user.UserId);
            var lookupQuery = lookup[someId];

            Console.WriteLine("\nLookup query results:");
            foreach (var r in lookupQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Users_id: {r.Users_id}, UserId: {r.UserId}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Linq query results:
Users_id: 1, UserId: 0042
Users_id: 5, UserId: 0042
Users_id: 6, UserId: 0042

Lookup query results:
Users_id: 1, UserId: 0042
Users_id: 5, UserId: 0042
Users_id: 6, UserId: 0042
```

Hope that clarifies things.  The major issue I see with your question and comments is that it's possible that you're mistaking nested classes for properties.  When you instantiate an outer class, the inner class does not get instantiated and it's not some sort of property of an outer class.

**Old answer (provides individual details):**

I like using Linq.  So, assuming `sampleList` is of type `list`:

```
var query = sampleList.UsersList.Where(user => user.UserId == someId);
```

That's going to give you `IEnumerable<list.Users>`.  You can always use `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, `ToDictionary()` to get the desired collection type:

```
var results = sampleList.UsersList.Where(user => user.UserId == someId).ToArray();
```

As far as `Lookup`, I've seen a few ways it being used, but the most familiar way for me is this:

```
var lookup = sampleList.UsersList.ToLookup(user => user.UserId);
var query = lookup[someId];
```

Once again, that'll give you `IEnumerable<list.Users>`.  Alternatively, you can get the collection type of your choice from that query:

```
var results = lookup[someId].ToArray();
```

Basically, you're specifying what the key will represent in that lookup (it's the `UserId` in this case) and then when the time comes, you search by a key.

Comment: @JuliusDoan That's not what I'm saying.  It's `list.UsersList.Where(....)`, not `list.Users.Where(...)`.  `Users` is a nested class, not a property or a method.  My examples are working with `UserList` public property of the `list` class.  Defining a nested class does not mean you instantiate it.  I think you're under impression that just because you have a nested class definition of `Users` in `list` that you can somehow call into it.  That's not how it works.

Comment: @JuliusDoan See my edited answer, which provides a great amount of detail.  That should clear things up.

Comment: Oh yes this works in the case you already know your sampleList, single entry. If you had more entries in sampleList you cant do this unless you go through every single item in that sampleList for looping or maybe a double where? To clarify sampleList should be of type List<list>. If i'm still wrong let me know.

Comment: @JuliusDoan I've no idea what you mean.  Your original code had no mention of `List<list>`.  Then only `List<T>` in there is your `UserList` property, which is of type `List<Users>`.  If you had multiple `list` objects (in a `List<T>`, for example), then it would be the exact same deal, with `Lookup` or `Linq`, you would just to adjust to look through a `List` of lists.  I gave you my answer based on the information you've provided in your question.

Comment: I found the answer I needed using 

var element = (from sublist in userList
               from item in sublist
               where item.uniqueidentifier == someid
               select item).FirstOrDefault();  Thanks!